# Define css for table inside a disabled div container

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have some markup HTML like this :

```
<div disabled="disabled">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        <tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I tried to define css for `tags` inside the table (th, td) for such condition (when Div is disabled) :

```
div[disabled="disabled"].table th,td{
    color:gray;
    ....
}
```

But it does not seem to work. Please tell me what'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: FYI, I don't believe the `disabled` attribute in a `div` is valid HTML: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes

Comment: @Michael_B unfortunately It's valid in IE8, I'm now upgrading an IE8 website to IE11, so ..... u know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You css should look like this

```css
div[disabled="disabled"] table th, 
div[disabled="disabled"] table td {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div disabled="disabled">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Lorem</th>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lorem</td>
        <tr>
    </table>
</div>
```